# FTP Not Working with Mobile Tethering

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ftp, android

I am not able to connect with my FTP Client (Filezilla) using mobile tethering. When I try to connect to my website, it says connection timed out. However when I use my sister’s phone for tethering, it connects well.

How can I fix that? I have to upload a lot of pages on server and my mobile internet connection is faster than my sister’s. I tried using FileZila and CoreFTP clients. I am using Windows 7 machine.

Answer (score 7):

Due to its architecture the FTP protocol does not work very well in environments making use of NAT. NAT is heavily used in mobile networks and the  used helper applications are sometimes buggy, which might explain the difference you see. There might be other reasons while it fails in one network but succeeds in the other but without having lots of details about the networks all is speculation.

I strongly recommend to move away from FTP and instead use SFTP, that is file transfer over SSH. FileZilla supports SFTP but you need an SSH server setup at the server side. But don't confuse SFTP with FTPS which is FTP with TLS and has even more problems in environments using NAT.

Comment: Your idea of using SFTP worked.

Comment: Additionally, you could resort to 'plain' FTP, i.e. not over TLS (TLS is the 'troublemaker'). Although SFTP is strongly prefered of course.

Comment: @pbond: usually FTP is enough of a troublemaker by itself because of the architecture which has control channel and data channels and in-band signaling where the data channel is expected. TLS adds to the trouble in cases, where there is some kind of FTP helper application at the network which fails to adapt the data channels if the it can not read/modify the in-band signaling due to an encrypted control channel.

Comment: @pbond: I chose the Encryption as "Use explicit FTP over TLS if available" and things started working. Thanks.